# Why Yii2 module separate configuration does not work in basic app?

Tags: configuration, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a yii2 basic application with 2 parts (web and service for mobile).

I have created a module to handle the restful requests fired from mobile . I want to configure this module to be rest. So I created a config file for this module in side the module directory. as mentioned in the [yii2 documentation for modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#module-classes)

/config/config.php:

```php
return [

'components' => [
  'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => array(

            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'mobile/mobile-clients',
                'extraPatterns' => ['GET search' => 'search']
            ],

        ),
    ],
    'request' => [
        'class' => '\yii\web\Request',
        'enableCookieValidation' => false,
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ],
    ],
]

];
```

the module class is as follows:

```php
<?php

namespace app\modules\Mobile;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Module;

class MobileService extends Module {

     public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\Mobile\controllers';

     public function init() {
         parent::init();     
         Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR     
                   .'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'config.php'));

     }
}
```

The problem is that the request component is not working as expected **while it works fine when configured in the application configuration (config/main.php)**

same for the urlManager.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to duplicate those components? Just copy the instances so there is only one of each. Never a good idea to duplicate components used all over the place

Comment: @robsch I want to customize the components of the mobile module to be restful that is all what I want,  Is this the right way

Comment: `.../modules/Mobile/config/config.php` This file does not exist?

Comment: @Ngô Văn Thao the file exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to my problem is to create api application that is a new application inside the yii2 basic app. It shares the models and the vendors directory but has its own configuration and entry script  (index.php). This is the [solution  link](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template) for more information .

**EDIT**:

Do not forget to add the user component in the api.config file

```
  'user' => [
  'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
  'enableAutoLogin' => false,
  ],
```

I think using yii2 advanced application structure is better for a case like mine. But this solution works perfect :) .

Best.

Comment: OMG... Was it so difficult for the one who wrote that tutorial to explain the URL path to connect to the new app within the project (api)? Could you help me?. In that "tutorial" how do you access the newly created api? An example URL is possible?

Comment: I have yii2_project/api/modules/v1/controllers/TestController.php. The url should be something like: http://myweb.com/api/v1/test (but nope)

Comment: I forgot that Yii2 pluralizes controllers in the endpoint URLs. Therefore the correct path would be: http://mysite/api/v1/tests. My mistake.